# AlertDialog doesn't fit long list & view & buttons if used together

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Some time ago I faced a problem with AlertDialog:

If it used with list adapter (via setAdpater/setSingleChoiceItems/setMultiChoiceItems) and custom view (via setView) and a buttons sometimes, and list is too long and doesn't fit dialog's height, my custom added view and dialog buttons were not showing... (it's showing, but not visible because moved down by listview)
here is a test code:

```
    final int TEST_COUNT = 20; //increase it if list fit your screen...
    List<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= TEST_COUNT; i++)
      list.add("item "+i);
    TextView testView = new TextView(this); //type of view doesn't matter
    testView.setText("test view");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, list);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder
            .setTitle("Test AlertDialog")
            .setAdapter(adapter, (dlg, which) -> {})
            .setView(testView) //this line broke all!
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", (dlg, which) -> dlg.dismiss())
            .setNegativeButton("No", (dlg, which) -> dlg.dismiss())
            .show();
```

I've searched on google and SO, but found no working solution, only one suggestion - write your own Dialog with custom layout... And I decided to find the truth.

Answer (score 1):

Because I didn't find working solution, I made an investigation and made my own.
First of all, I checked default AlertDialog layout and sources:

1. [alert_dialog_material.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_material.xml)
2. [AlertDialog.java](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0-source/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.java.html)
3. [AlertController.java](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/appcompat/appcompat/1.1.0-source/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertController.java.html)

links above were found in google, you can check sources in your IDE of course.

As we can understand from layout's xml - root AlertDialogLayout view is inherited from LinearLayout(Compat), all children are with height = WRAP_CONTENT.
But we need listview was fitted in space between title and our custom view.
And solution I've found - set "contentPanel" view's weight to 1.
Here is example code solves the problem, just replace **.show()** to **.create()** in first piece of code from question:

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(dlg -> {
        AlertDialog adlg = (AlertDialog)dlg;
        View v = adlg.getWindow().findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
        if (v != null)
            ((LinearLayoutCompat.LayoutParams)v.getLayoutParams()).weight = 1;
    });
dialog.show();
```

Of course it will works till google change something in their default alertdialog layout...

Maybe someone may offer a better solution?

Thank you for your attention!